# Conversion from string "System.Data.DataRowView" to type 'Integer' is not valid error

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB.NET. I want to retrive data from one field of an Access database into a listbox and sort data from min to max value. But I received an error message:

> "Conversion from string "System.Data.DataRowView" to type 'Integer' is not valid"

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
Please provide at least the code in textual form instead of as a picture.

Answer (score 0):

You declared `arr(i)` array as **Integer** and you writing `arr(i) = resListBox.Items(i).ToString`..
How's this possible??

Say your `resListBox.Items(i)` has value "abc" then abc cannot be inserted into a type int variable. And even `.ToString` converts it into string and passes the string value.

Try `arr(i) = resListBox.Items(i).Text` but only if the value is in integer or else it will throw the exception again...!

Comment: Try writing code into `Try..Catch` so that you can view the error in the debug mode even with your program running...!

Answer (score 0):

As bonny has already said in his answer you can't assign a string to an integer.

You could try using  [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) method. This way you test to see if the  value is an integer and then you can either assign it to the variable if returns true or display messagebox to show value is either null or not an integer.

```
     Dim number As Integer
     Dim result As Boolean = Int32.TryParse(resListBox.Items(i).Text, number)
     If result Then
        arr(i) = resListBox.Items(i).Text
     Else
        MessageBox.Show("Attempted conversion of '{0}' failed.", 
                          If(resListBox.Items(i).Text Is Nothing, "<null>", resListBox.Items(i).Text))
     End If
```